# Python not modifying global variable

Tags: python, django, function

I have the below code:

```
failure = ""
def walk(dictItems):
    returnVal = ""
    for key, item in dictItems.items():
        if isinstance(item,dict):
            walk(item)
        else:
            returnVal = returnVal +"<li>"+key+" : "+ item + "</li>"
        global failure
        failure = returnVal
dictItems={"personal_details":{"phone*":"","nationality*":"MW","id_number*":"","gender*":"MALE","title*":"MR","surname":"","marital_status*":"MARRIED","first_name*":"","dob*":"","id_type*":"BUSINESS.REG"},"residential_details":{"city":"","location":"","residence_physical_address":""}}
walk(dictItems)
print(failure)
```

**failure** variable is always null despite having values on **returningVal** any help?

Comment: `failure` is declared outside the function so there is no need in using the `global` keyword. Also, add an example of `dictItems` to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Armaggheddon How there is no need to use the **global**!!

Comment: What is the scope of this function, i am getting output here with dummy dictionary, can you please update with dictItems?

Comment: Your code seems fine, try to add some example of input of function.

Comment: Oh, had a miss on the language for a second XD Yes, global is required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see, you reset every time `returnVal` therefore when you assign it to `failure` is empty. Change your code to this:

```
failure = ""
def walk(dictItems):
    for key, item in dictItems.items():
        if isinstance(item,dict):
            walk(item)
        else:
            global failure
            failure += "<li>"+key+" : "+ item + "</li>"
dictItems={"personal_details":{"phone*":"","nationality*":"MW","id_number*":"","gender*":"MALE","title*":"MR","surname":"","marital_status*":"MARRIED","first_name*":"","dob*":"","id_type*":"BUSINESS.REG"},"residential_details":{"city":"","location":"","residence_physical_address":""}}
walk(dictItems)
print(failure)
```

Comment: Maybe the name `failure` for the final output is a bit misleading so maybe `result` would be more accurate since no longer exists as an internal variable of the function `walk()` with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you you are iterating over a dictionary with sub-dictionarys so calling walk wen you hit a sub-dictionary sets the failure value to only the keys and items of the sub-dictionary. You should add, not set to failure. Or walk() should return like this:

```
    dictItems = {
        "key1":"item1",
        "key2":"item2",
        "key3":{
            "subkey1":"subitem1",
            "subkey2":"subitem2"
        },
        "key4":"item4"
    }
    
    def walk(dictItems):
        returnVal = ""
        for key, item in dictItems.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                returnVal += walk(item)
            else:
                returnVal += "<li>"+key+" : "+ item + "</li>"
        return returnVal
    print(walk(dictItems))
```